# Should duplicate question can be removable if one or more answers are given?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Recently i have post a question on stack overflow. After sometime i have realize that the question is already posted before and it is duplicate. But, before deleting the question some answers are already given and also the question  is voted for **possible duplicate post**. The posted question has been closed for duplicate post. Now my question is that. **Should my question be deleted?** if it should be, then how do I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is clear, constructive, and properly formatted then we do not need to delete it when closed as a duplicate. And specially if it has good answers. Because your duplicate question can help the future users to search the original question. And we can not delete question if it has an upvoted answer or more than one answers. But if you think your question is almost exact duplicate and you can't delete it (due to multiple/upvoted answers) you can flag your question and ask the moderators to delete it with satisfactory reason. But if it is me, I don't delete it as users have invested their time to answer my question.

Also note deleting questions *may* lead you to [the post ban storm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/187824).